# GLKView not working if instantiated in custom class

Tags: ios, swift, opengl-es, glkview

This doesn't works in a new Swift project. Gives me a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=1 error` in AppDelegate.

**UIViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        Test(view: view)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

**Test.swift**

```
import UIKit
import GLKit
import OpenGLES

final class Test: NSObject {
    init(view: UIView) {
        super.init()
        let context = EAGLContext(API: EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2)
        EAGLContext.setCurrentContext(context)
        let glView = GLKView(frame: view.bounds)
        glView.context = context
        glView.delegate = self
        view.addSubview(glView)
    }
}

extension Test: GLKViewDelegate {
    func glkView(view: GLKView, drawInRect rect: CGRect) {
        glClearColor(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
        glClear(GLbitfield(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT))
    }
}
```

Putting all the code inside the `ViewController` does work.

I am building a bigger application that has a similar setup to this. But getting a lot `EXC_BREAKPOINT code=1 errors`. This error differs if I run in simulator.

Comment: take a look in your logs. it will bring more details about the error. Please provide this so we can help.

Comment: So far it seems that the delegate needs to be a ViewController. Not sure why, maybe I am missing something obvious.